# Copy first and last entry from CSV to worksheet

Tags: csv

I'm very new to this but I need some help.

I have data where I need the first and last entry from column 6 of a csv file (554 in total) and copy that to a single worksheet. The csvs all have different ranges. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the programming angle to this question? What language are you using, what code do you have and what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "pickme="
FOR /f "tokens=6delims=," %%a IN (q28017030.csv) DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED pickme ECHO %%a
 SET "pickme=%%a"
)
ECHO %pickme%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28017030.csv` containing this data for my testing.

```
big,fat,hairy,worksheet,under,discussion,here
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,bingo,data7
```

Producing

```
discussion
bingo
```

which I believe is what you require.

Note that this solution assumes that columns 1..6 data do not contain commas - the only commas are column-separators. Also that the columns 1..5 are not empty.

`pickme` is initially cleared, so is `undefined` when the `for` loop reads the first line. The column is thus `echo`ed and `pickme` becomes defined after the first (header) line is encountered. It is then updated as each line is read, so we need to `echo` the very last value encountered.

---

Ah - 550 or so **files** not **columns**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR %%f IN (q28017030*.csv) DO ( 
 SET "pickme="
 FOR /f "tokens=6delims=," %%a IN (%%f) DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED pickme ECHO %%a
  SET "pickme=%%a"
 )
 CALL ECHO %%pickme%%
)
)>new.txt

type new.txt
```

GOTO :EOF

Produces newfile.txt

I set it to scan only for `.csv`s pattern "q28017030*.csv" for convenience of testing. `*.csv` would scan all the CSVs.

Comment: Hi Magoo, thanks for getting back to me. It looks like what I am needing, you may have saved me a lot of time. Is there a way to loop this across all the csv files within the folder (over 550)? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again Magoo, Sorry my blurb didn't give the scale of how many files I needed to deal with (for this first part of the project). The script worked perfectly, the final tweaks gave me this;                            @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR %%f IN (*.csv) DO ( 
 SET "KP="
 FOR /f "Skip=1 tokens=6delims=," %%a IN (%%f) DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED KP ECHO V.AL.S,%%a
  SET "KP=%%a"
 )
 CALL ECHO V.AL.E,%%KP%%
)
)>AL-KP.csv

type AL-KP.csv

GOTO :EOF